# How to add 15 APs to Radius Server on ubuntu server

Tags: radius

I want to install a RADIUS server on Ubuntu but I am not sure it can support  more than 15 Access Points at a time.

Each AP will have 10 users.

Answer (score 1):

FreeRADIUS is free software. It has no artificial limitations on number of devices supported.

15 access points is absolutely a trivial amount of devices, and with a total of 150 users even a low end machine, such as a Raspberry Pi should be able to keep up with the authentication traffic.